# Linear function and expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

At first we have a function f supposed to be convex.

Show that if $E(f(X))=f(E(X))$, where X is a random variable, it implies that $X=E(X)$ almost surely.

$E(f(X))=f(E(X))$, by Jensen's inequality, I deduced that the function f is linear... But it feels kind of wrong as Jensen's inequality also says that $X=E(X)$ almost surely only if the function is strictly convex... Am I right?

Any help is welcomed!

Thanks a lot, David

Comment: Could you explain me why please?

Comment: Maybe there is an error in your problem statement. Are you supposed to assume that $E[f(X)] = f(E[X])$ for almost all measurable functions $f(\cdot)$? Because if $f(\cdot)$ is restricted to be a linear (or affine) function, then $E[f(X)] = f(E[X])$ holds regardless of whether $X=E[X]$ almost surely or not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am supposed to assume that at first f is a convex function. 
Then given the assumption E[f(X)]=f(E[X]), it implies that X = E[X] almost surely.

Comment: Then how about **editing** your problem to include all the relevant information? -1 pending a correct and complete statement of the problem to be solved.

Comment: Well if f is linear, I didn't think that it is usefull to know that at first f is supposed to be convex..
Sorry for this, I will edit my post. Still your help would be appreciated @DilipSarwate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the *Jensen's Inequality*, for a convex function $f$ and positive numbers $\alpha_i$ with unit summation, we have:

$$f(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\ldots+\alpha_nx_n)\leq\alpha_1f(x_1)+\alpha_2f(x_2)+\ldots\alpha_nf(x_n)$$
with equality if and only if $f$ is linear **or** $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$

The important thing that you must pay attention to, is that there is an **or** between conditions of equality. So you can deduce that $X=E(X)$, **or** $f$ is linear. In the textbooks of information theory such as *Cover's* book, it has been mentioned that $X=E(X)$ only when the function is **strictly** convex, so in that case, the function cannot be linear, and hence equality holds if and only if $X=E(X)$.

Note that you cannot deduce from $E(f(X))=f(E(X))$, that $X=E(X)$, since if you let $f(X)=aX+b$, then the equality holds even if $X\neq E(X)$

Comment: I think I have not understand your comment. Explain more please

Comment: So, the question is incorrect, since if you let $f(X)=aX+b$, then the equality holds, even if $X\neq E(X)$.

Comment: My question @AMIR asks you how to show that $E(f(X))=f(E(X))$ implies $X=E(X)$ $a.s.$. 
As $E(f(X))=f(E(X))$, you can deduce that f is linear.
Therefore, by Jensen, my problem is false... As I need a function strictly convex to imply $X=E(X)$ $a.s.$.
Okay. Thanks for your help and sorry if I was confused.